# UICollectionview images with pagecontrol in swift4

Tags: uicollectionviewcell, swift4

if i am using display images using collection view does not display (design) images properly. but i want to display the images following method.[image]

if i am using UICollectionView images first 9 images are displayed properly with horizontal scrollview (Direction). But next image(10) continue space images.

how to display the images with page control. if am using UICollectionView page control problem will be there. How can i display the images using page control functionality(like given image)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** to manage images like your design ...

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize.init(width: ScreenWidth/2-10 , height: 160)//you can return a/c to your design 

}
```

and you handle page control with **scroll view delegate** method like this ... just make one thing that u have **enabled collection view paging property**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentValue = Int(collectionView.contentOffset.x/ScreeWidth)//here u will get value for page control to set current page ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. If i have a 10 images in collectionview. first 9 images are displayed in first page(like image). 10th image display in new page when the scroll the collection view extra spaces displayed empty space.

Comment: @VigneshJeyaraj "10th image display in new page when the scroll the collection view extra spaces displayed empty space" I m not getting this point that you want that space or not .. or want in another way.. if its possible then add one more screenshot